# How is crime addressed according to (radical) pacifism?

Tags: pacifism

[Pacifism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacifism) is the opposition to war and violence. Most pacifists propose to abolish the army, such as [Costa Rica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_of_Costa_Rica) and a small number of other nations have done. Some also propose to abolish the police. In this case, how do they propose to address violent crime?

Comment: Maybe they just talk with the criminal, sorry I couldn't hold it.

Comment: Could you name a group of such pacifists?

Comment: I've met them in person, but I can't find any groups on the web right now. I've asked at http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/282/130

Comment: Are you asking how they propose to deal with it in theory, or how they actually manage to deal with it in practice?

Comment: The former, as no societies governed by strictly pacifist laws have ever existed, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @gerrit - Would you agree to impose requirement to only seriously agree to upvote and accept ways of addressing that explicitly account for the reality that ~1% of society are psychopaths based on various studies (DSM-IV gives 3% for men and 1% for women). Frankly, most "pacifists" I ever dealt with completely ignore that fact.

Comment: @DVK — Well, my question is what has been proposed, not whether I would believe that it would actually work. Although I strongly suspect that pacifists would propose to treat psychopaths as being sick rather than criminal.

Comment: @gerrit - that assumes that (1) You CAN "heal" psychopaths (Colockwork Orange anyone?); and (2) that said psychopaths will agree to be "treated" without violently colmpulsing then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6660/discussion-between-gerrit-and-dvk)

Comment: Most 'pacifists' tend to allow certain limited use of force such as police officers working under restricted rules for their use of force.  Of course 'radical' pacifists may refuse any use of force even for police, but to be frank the 'radical' branch of any philosophy tend to take things to such extremes as to make the philosophy they endorse impractical if not actively self defeating.  Ie don't judge a philosophy by it's radical element, just accept the most extreme ends of the radical spectrum tend to take things to such excess as to be non-functional.

Comment: @user4012 just to be clear many psychopaths aren't violent in modern days, in fact they are overrepresented in the tops of industry and business.  Though one can easily argue that is only because society has a method in place to penalize violence (ie cops who can respond with more force) that violence is not deemed a viable means to get what they want.  It's quite likely in a hypothetical world were no one would use force psychopaths would find it the best way to get what they want, but my point is more to counter the view of modern psychopaths as all just crazed serial killers.

Comment: In the pacifist church I am a member of, it is absolutely allowed for their to be police who forcibly arrest people. I'm unaware of any similar group that advocates abolition of the police. I'm aware of groups that advocate abolition of police in their current form, but all call for replacing them with other units that do the same thing (possibly under a different name). The only ones I know calling for total abolition of police functions are radical anarchists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frankly, the only seemingly well-explained example I found of a pacifist openly discussing the topics on the web ([interview with  Tripp York](http://rachelheldevans.com/blog/ask-a-pacifist-response), who is a pacifist from Christian standpoint and an author of "[A Faith Not Worth Fighting For: Addressing Commonly Asked Questions about Christian Nonviolence](https://wipfandstock.com/store/A_Faith_Not_Worth_Fighting_ForPREORDER_BY_APRIL_5TH_Addressing_Commonly_Asked_Questions_about_Christian_Nonviolence)" from Cascade Books), the answer really was... no answer.

When someone asked whether in practice, pacifists merely "outsource" the violence to others (e.g. call the cops), his response was that (1) Yes, that is true, and (2) His personal solution to that was "gardening". No elaboration was produced on what happens if his family is threatened while gardening - would he NOT call the cops?

The same vague approach abounds. For example, when asked about Hitler, his response seems to be summarizable as "you should speak out, and if necessary get arrested" (presumably, protesting). How such an approach would have, in any way, shape or form, stop Hitler, is left unaddressed. He also quotes, ironically, Malcolm X.

The interview did point out several books which may contain deeper answers, but if those books contained better answers, he surely would have referred to such. "[What About Hitler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1587430657)" is one.

---

One a more serious note, radical pacifism seems like an implausible approach from game-theoretical viewpoint. It's inherently an unstable strategy. For an example of a great explanation of why, we need look no futher than the classic "Selfish Gene" by Richard Dawkins - in "Aggression: stability and the selfish machine" chapter he models pacifist (he calls it "dove") strategy, and concludes that it is not evolutionary stable - a small minority of hawks (aggressive violent strategists) have a tremendous advantage. Given that human society, as a rule, contains at least 1% psychopaths (source: DSM-IV), pacifism (complete rejection of violence) as a global solution simply can not work - without more nuanced strategies employing aggression, psyhopaths (hawks) will propagate and win till there are ~ 1/2th of population of them. In other words, anything proposed as a solution by radical pacifists is unlikely to **actually** work in current reality.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, radical pacifists seem to have no strong answer other than vague platitudes that ignore human nature. People love to conveniently forget why society as a whole exists:

- [Hitler](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1877299) exists and is used as an example of why radical pacifism does not work. Hitler even told the British and British fascists to handle Gandhi by shoot Gandhi, and if this doesn't suffice to reduce them to submission, shoot a dozen leading members of the Congress, and if that doesn't suffice shoot 200, and so on, as you make it clear that you mean business."
- People love to ask how humans would exist without empathy, but forget people who lack [empathy](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/25288/25157) exist. As I described in another answer:

> While not a peer-reviewed study per se, but the DSM-5 says that the prevalence of Narcissistic Personality Disorder in the population is 6.2%, or approximately one out of sixteen members of the population (6.25%). The DSM-V was published in 2013 and is a peer-reviewed text, so it is within the 10-year criteria you mentioned and this fact is mentioned in more recent sources like an article for Psychiatric Times published in 2016. Another study from 2019 doesn't mention Narcissistic Personality Disorder, but does mention how approximately 3% of the population has Antisocial Personality Disorder, another disorder that is a common dual-diagnosis with Narcissistic Personality Disorder. Then, there is a 2020 study that shows 1.6% to 5.9% of people have borderline personality disorder or BPD, which can be associated with a lack of empathy and lead to behaviors that can be mistaken for NPD. This is similar to Histrionic Personality Disorder (which doesn't cause people to suffer from a lack of empathy like with NPD, but can appear that way due to how it is difficult for those with HPD to recognize the emotions of others and thus lack emotional intelligence) that affects less than or equal to 2% of the population according to the University of Arizona College of Medicine.

Speaking of Hitler, he was diagnosed with the condition histrionic personality disorder by the German psychologist Kar Wilmanns before he ever was a dictator as described in the German history writing Highdelberg: Zur Kulturgeschichte der Genussmittel und psychoaktiven Drogen, a mental condition [associated](https://doi.org/10.1053%2Fcomp.2000.16560) [with](https://doi.org/10.1007%2Fs11469-019-00139-5) [shallow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histrionic_personality_disorder) emotions. The point is that a lot of selfish and terrible people exist and a [lot](https://wipfandstock.com/store/A_Faith_Not_Worth_Fighting_ForPREORDER_BY_APRIL_5TH_Addressing_Commonly_Asked_Questions_about_Christian_Nonviolence) of rebuttals kind of give vague answers that ignore this reality.

Plus, Peter Gelderloos wrote in his book *How Nonviolence Protects the State* how staying nonviolent for too long in authoritarian societies like Nazi Germany only allows the repressive state to grow in power, so the radical pacifist answer of "you should speak out, and if necessary get arrested" does not work if the government is willing to end your life and come up with a good enough propaganda reason why you need to die.