# Does radical pacifism reject police violence?

Tags: police, pacifism

[Pacifism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacifism) is the opposition to war and violence. Does radical pacifism reject the use of violence by the police force?

See also: [How is crime addressed according to (radical) pacifism?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/274/130)

Comment: I've clarified the question, I mean the use of violence by the police. Rejecting the use of violence against the police is a lot more common than the reverse.

Comment: Thanks @gerrit, the disconnect was on my end. Just an 'oh, duh!' moment on a Sunday evening.

Comment: @gerrit - Thanks for clarification. Doesn't any answer to the linked question answer this one by corollary?

Comment: @DVK it does, but I decided to split up the question because as pointed out in the comments there, I'm not actually sure if it does. I've met people who are against police violence, but they were anarchists, not sure if they were pacifists.

Comment: Hm... I am not an expert, but it seems to me the question would greatly benefit from either explicitly identifying specific strains of "radical pacifism", ideally by naming the main thinkers/personalities you are thinking of. As it is, there seem to be a great many people considering themselves pacifists, with extremely varying ideologies and all over the board views, making this hard to answer objectively.

Comment: i suspect that if it didn't, it wouldn't be called "radical" pacifism, just pacifism

Answer (score 2):

Groups that avow extreme forms of pacifism — [Mennonites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mennonites), the [Society of Friends (aka Quakers)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quakers), philosophical [anarcho-pacifists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-pacifism), etc. - reject all forms of violence, whether between states, between a state an its citizens, or between citizens. This would include police violence. Such groups usually use a community intervention model to deal with transgressors, with penalties that might range from counseling by elders to community sanctions to expulsion from the community. Generally speaking, all pacifists will hold that problems are best resolved through discussion and reparation, with the assumption that transgressors will respond appropriately to religious or philosophical arguments.