# Why is radical pacifism so rare in Croatia? Why does almost nobody believe Franjo Tuđman did a good thing by not sending weapons to Vukovar?

Tags: history, pacifism, yugoslavia

Regarding Vukovar Massacre, as far as I can see, beliefs in Croatia range from the one expressed by BBC News at the time:

> Croat defenders of Vukovar later claimed that the town could have been saved from capture by Serb forces if the nationalist President Franjo Tudjman had been willing to send reinforcements.
> Mr Tudjman was accused of deliberately sacrificing Vukovar - dubbed the Croatian Stalingrad because of its devastation - so as to reinforce his portrayal of Croatia as the victim of Serb aggression.
> https://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/europe/2988304.stm

to the belief that is taught in schools in Croatia, namely, that Tuđman was willing to send weapons to Vukovar but that it was not possible to deliver them. An example of such a claim from enciklopedija.hr (basically, the Croatian equivalent of Conservapedia):

> Osvojenjem Mirkovaca 1. X. 1991. JNA je uspjela izolirati Vukovar te u njega više nije bilo moguće dopremati pomoć.
> https://enciklopedija.hr/natuknica.aspx?id=65649

But what is amazing to me is that almost nobody believes (and people call me childish for expressing that belief) that Franjo Tuđman did the right thing by not sending weapons to Vukovar. How do you know what would have happened if weapons were delivered to the Croatian army in Vukovar? Maybe Vukovar Massacre would have still happened even if the Croatian army had weapons, maybe there would just have been more violence. Am I missing something and that belief is absurd for some reason I do not see?

And even if we take for granted Vukovar Massacre could have been prevented by weapons, would not armed civilians been a better solution than the military? Armed civilians does not require coercion, military does.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last paragraph?  Whatever the pros and cons of a pacifist approach, *armed civilians* seems to risk weakening the distinction between legitimate, *military*, targets and targeting civilians which is a war crime.

Comment: Radical pacifism is rare *everywhere*. I doubt Croatia is especially unusual in the respect.  Whatever the true reason that Vukovar wasn't re-inforced, it isn't because Tudman was a pacifist.

Comment: @JamesK I would expect the countries where there has been a bloody war in living memory to be full of radical pacifists. Apparently, Croatia is not, for some reason.

Comment: Can you give a single example of a country which has recently been at war in which is full of radical pacifists.  Is Serbia loaded with pacifists?  Is Ukraine? Is Syria or Libya or (etc etc)

Comment: Its not the same, but look at https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-is-crime-addressed-according-to-radical-pacifism

Comment: @JamesK Japan developed quite a strong radical pacifist movement. I can not tell how popular it was quickly after WWII, though.